# Unsupported property *password

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a CloudFormation stack template which contains a DataPipeline resource having an RdsDatabase object:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  ProUsageReportsPipelineStg:
    Type: AWS::DataPipeline::Pipeline 
    Properties: 
      Name: my-db
      PipelineObjects:
        - id: ProAccountDB
          type: RdsDatabase
          region: us-west-2
          username: username
          "*password": password
          rdsInstanceId: mydb
```

When I try to create this stack, I get the following error:

```
Encountered unsupported property *password
```

However, according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-rdsdatabase.html) that is the place to pass the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close. The correct syntax would be something like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  ProUsageReportsPipelineStg:
    Type: AWS::DataPipeline::Pipeline 
    Properties: 
      Name: my-db
      PipelineObjects:
        -
          Id: ProAccountDB
          Name: "My Pro Account database"
          Fields:
            - 
              Key: "type"
              StringValue: "RdsDatabase"
            -
              Key: "region"
              StringValue: "us-west-2"
            -
              Key: "username"
              StringValue: "username"
            -
              Key: "*password"
              StringValue: "password"
            -
              Key: "rdsInstanceId"
              StringValue: "mydb"
```

You can also check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-datapipeline-pipeline.html#w2ab2c21c10d268c13) example in the AWS docs for reference.